# A question on circles and triangles - Please check my answer

Tags: geometry

O and O' are the centres of circle of radii 20 cm and 37 cm. If AB = 24 cm, what is the distance OO'?

[image: enter image descriptfion here]

I have tried it (see answer below...) but I don't know whether I am right or wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is spot on. You do have a miscalculation, though.
$20^2 = 400$, $12^2 = 144$, $400-144 = 256$, so the first distance $CO = 16$. The second distance $CO'$ is right. 
So, I would say that the answer is $51$ cm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have done...

1. Since $AB = 24$ cm then $AC = 12$ cm
2. $AO = 20$ cm AND $AO' = 37$ cm (Because they are the radii of the respective circles)
3. So by Pythagorean theorem, $CO = \sqrt{AO^2 - AC^2} = \sqrt{20^2 - 12^2}= 16$ cm.
4. Doing the same for $CO'$, we get .. $CO'= 35$ cm

So the final answer comes to be $51$ cm....

Comment: Looks right to me.  Is there any step that you are unsure about?

Comment: It was just that I was getting the wrong answer...until @jasotastic CORRECTED my silly MISTAKE.... By the way do you know of a short-cut FASTER METHOD that I can use in Multiple CHoice Questions since they dont require the STEPS ONLY an ANswer SO that I can Save time..